# EF Fluent API - HasIndex for complex field

Tags: entity-framework, indexing, ef-fluent-api

I need to use Fluent API (no DataAnnotation) and should create complex Index (3 fields). I try to do it:

```
        this.HasIndex(p => p.LoadId).HasName("IX_UniqueLoad").IsUnique();
        this.HasIndex(p => p.LocationId).HasName("IX_UniqueLoad").IsUnique();
        this.HasIndex(p => p.StopAction).HasName("IX_UniqueLoad").IsUnique();
```

but it says:

> The index with name 'IX_UniqueLoad' on table 'dbo.Stop' has the same
>   column order of '-1' specified for columns 'LoadId' and 'LocationId'.
>   Make sure a different order value is used for the IndexAttribute on
>   each column of a multi-column index.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
this.HasIndex(p => new { p.LoadId, p.LocationId, p.StopAction }).IsUnique();
```

it will generates:

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Stop", new[] { "LoadId", "LocationId", "StopAction" }, unique: true);
```